# Pycharm find usages of duck typed property

Tags: python, pycharm

Consider the following (meaningless) minimal example:

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, some_list):
        self._some_list = some_list
     
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._some_list)
    
    @property
    def get_len(self):
        return len(self._some_list)

instance = MyClass([1,2,3])
len(instance)  # works
instance.get_len   # works as well, but less pythonic?
```

Assume the duck type is meaningful here, then it would seem that implementing `__len__` is more python. I wonder though if I were to ever refactor this, could I find usages using pycharm (or any other IDE?). If not, it seems like the less pythonic version has a clear advantage.

Comment: I'm not really sure what's the "clear advantage" there. `len` isn't something you'd commonly need to find all usages of.

Comment: but how can you safely refactor?

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd need to refactor `len` calls of one class, specifically.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your example in pycharm and the usage of `__len__` is not found.

> PyCharm 2023.1 (Community Edition) Build #PC-231.8109.197

Comment: yeah I am aware, so I am wondering how one would usually go about refactoring it.